# Considerations for long UPS battery life

Tags: batteries, ups, lifetime

I have brought my APC Smart UPS (750VA) to a local UPS merchant and service company to a checkup recently and I asked a new pair of CSB batteries for it. I have used a few types of batteries for this UPS and experienced that CSB batteries were the long lasting ones and its price worth the less frequent recalibration and battery ordering-replacement procedures for me. (I mean here the lifetime of the battery, not the running time in case of AC power loss.)

During the takeover they said that premium batteries (like CSB) are not always the best choice for every UPS (depending on the condition of the UPS), it might perform better with lower quality batteries. After the checkup they will suggest the best one for this specific UPS.

I've asked for details but we didn't get too far. An old regular car might not get the best performance from a new sports car component... - they said.

Could be any reason to use non-premium batteries for the longest battery life or they just have higher margin on cheaper batteries? What should I consider for the longest battery life (with APC Smart UPS-es)?

Comment: for example, suppose the UPS was manufactured 10 years ago ... the highest quality batteries, at that time, could be the cheapies of today ... the UPS may not be able to make use of the enhancements of modern batteries

Answer (score 0):

CSB is a (Hitachi) brand name for the generic battery type called *Valve Regulated Lead-Acid*, or VRLA battery. VRLA batteries also go by the name of *Sealed Lead-Acid* (SLA.)

I don't know if CSB (Hitachi) VRLAs are any better than a competitor's (and there are many.) You should contact APC directly and get their feedback on using batteries other than the CSB brand.